# Zend_PDF drawImage turns images black

Tags: image, zend-framework, pdf

I used Zend_PDF's drawImage to draw images in a pdf. I check the images for aspect ratio since they are either horizontal or vertical. And then draw them into my PDF. All horizontal images turn out well. All vertical images turn black, but some not completely. It seems like colors are inverted. You can still see some parts of the image. The jpeg's all look good to me.

```
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

$orientation = $this->checkAspect($imageFullPath);
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imageFullPath);

if($orientation == 'vertical') {
    $imgWidth = 475;
    $imgHeight = 672; // DINA4 shrinked to 475 width
    $x = 68; // margin left
    $y = 130; // start bottom
    $page->drawImage($image, $x, $y, $x + $imgWidth, $y + $imgHeight);  
} else {
    $imgWidth = 500;
    $imgHeight = 330;
    $x = 68; // margin left
    $y = 450; // start bottom
    $page->drawImage($image, $x, $y, $x + $imgWidth, $y + $imgHeight);  
}
```

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was simple. It had nothing to do with the images beeing vertical or horizontal but rather with colorspace. The vertical images, for some reason are all in CMYK and the horizontal images RGB.

Converted all images and now everything is fine.